# About django url why will be overwrite?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-urls

IT's my file tree

```
____mysite
 |____db.sqlite3
 |____dealwith_Time
 | |______init__.py
 | |______init__.pyc
 | |____admin.py
 | |____admin.pyc
 | |____migrations
 | | |______init__.py
 | | |______init__.pyc
 | |____models.py
 | |____models.pyc
 | |____tests.py
 | |____urls.py
 | |____urls.pyc
 | |____views.py
 | |____views.pyc
 |____manage.py
 |____mysite
 | |______init__.py
 | |______init__.pyc
 | |____settings.py
 | |____settings.pyc
 | |____urls.py
 | |____urls.pyc
 | |____wsgi.py
 | |____wsgi.pyc
```

and about root urls.py file it's about

```
url(r'^dealwith_Time/$',include('dealwith_Time.urls')),
url(r'^dealwith_Time/12$',include('dealwith_Time.urls')),
```

and deal with_Time's urls are

```
url(r'^$', 'dealwith_Time.views.current_datetime'),
url(r'^/12$', 'dealwith_Time.views.hour_ahead'),
```

and show my deal with_Time's views

```
def current_datetime(request):
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  html = "<html><body> It is now %s.</body></html>" %now
  return HttpResponse(html)

def hour_ahead(request):
  return HttpResponse("victory")
```

the question is when I access the `localhost:8000/dealwith_time` it worked.and response the time .but when I access the `localhost:8000/dealwith_time/12` .it's still response the time !and use the views's current_time function Rather than use `hour_ahead` function and print `"victory"`.....why i so confused please help me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `$` signs at the end of urls in  `root`'s `urls.py`. That means that url has to match exactly (not just beginning). So in your example url matches to second entry in `root`'s `urls.py` and empty string is passed to `with_Time`'s `urls.py` so it will match first entry and display time.

If you are including other urls files you normally want to use regex without `$`, so it will match the beginning of url and remaining will be passed to included urls file.

To correct your example use this for `root`'s `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^dealwith_Time/',include('dealwith_Time.urls')),
```

note that I've removed `$`, so `/dealwith_time/12` and `/dealwith_time/` will be both matched and `12` in first case will be passed to the next level.

And use this for `with_Time`'s `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^$', 'dealwith_Time.views.current_datetime'),
url(r'^12$', 'dealwith_Time.views.hour_ahead'),
```

note that I've removed `/` in second line as it will be stripped in root's `urls.py`.

Comment: ok. I know that .It just like root's urls.py has to match my two lines code in my deal_time's urls.py. and if line one can match and  match exactly and empty string is passed  So i just see time?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

```
url(r'^dealwith_Time/$',include('dealwith_Time.urls')),
```

for

```
url(r'^dealwith_Time/',include('dealwith_Time.urls')),
```

The $ sign overrides `dealwith_Time/12` and would override anything that came after the foward slash sign.

Take a look at [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).